# TFS 2012 Update 3 Continuous Integration and automatic deployment

Tags: tfs, msbuild, build-automation

I'm hoping someone can help me with putting me in the right direction for setting up automatic deployment from my tfs server to my web server.

I have a build definition set up with the following MSBuild arguments:

```
/p:AllowUntrustedCertificate=true /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=[profileName].pubxml
```

I get the ERROR_USER_UNAUTHORIZED message. If I add 
    `/p:Password=[passwordHere]` for the password of the account in the publishprofile
then it deploys succesfully. Is there a way I can do this so I don't have the password in the build definition?

I saw this post: [How do I configure MSBuild to use a saved publishProfile for WebDeploy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4890289/how-do-i-configure-msbuild-to-use-a-saved-publishprofile-for-webdeploy) 
which looks like it can be done, however it's not clear to me how so. If i can somehow use Windows Authentication that would be nice instead of Basic. I have tried adding the `/p:AuthType=NTLM` but this doesn't seem to do anything. I've tried passing an empty username as some have suggested, but that does not work either. Tried following this as well [How do I deploy using MSDeploy and TeamCity with Integrated Windows Authentication?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8053441/how-do-i-deploy-using-msdeploy-and-teamcity-with-integrated-windows-authenticati)

The destination Web Server is Server 2012 IIS 8 and TFS/Build Server is running Win 2008 SP2 with TFS 2012 Update 3 and both have web deploy v3.5 installed.

Answer (score 0):

You really want to be doing the release independent of the compilation. You will need to promote the same build through your environments. You can do this OOB using the LabTemplate.xaml and configuring environments. That is however not the only way:

1. Custom build process - hard to maintain and automate
2. Standard Environments - http://nakedalm.com/standard-environments-for-automated-deployment-and-testing/
3. Octopus Deploy - Best cheap solution out there
4. InRelease - OOB in TFS 2013 this tool adds lots of workflow goodness

Check out : http://nakedalm.com/release-management-with-team-foundation-server-2012/