# Web Deploy Handler 404 error

Tags: webdeploy-3.5

I'm using web deploy to remotely install my website that is in packaged zip file that I created via VS2015 publish wizard. When I run msdeploy.exe I get a 404 error. If I use a false password I get and error 'using web management service, but could not authorize', thus I know I getting connectivity through the right service.

I've followed this guide to do the setup, I've choosen Web Deploy Handler as my method
[http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/deployment/configuring-server-environments-for-web-deployment/configuring-a-web-server-for-web-deploy-publishing-web-deploy-handler][1]

I tired the manual install of web deploy as described here
[[Getting a 404 from WMSvc via MSDeploy.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13870561/getting-a-404-from-wmsvc-via-msdeploy-exe][1])

One thing that is suspicious is if I type this on the remote server https://myIp/MSDeploy.axd?site=MySite I get There is a problem with this website’s security certificate (do you want to continue)

any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This what I did to get it working.

This way resulted in 404

```
msdeploy.exe -source:package='...\mywebapp.zip' 
-dest:auto,computerName='https://MyServer/MSDeploy.axd?site=MyWebSiteName'
,userName='myusername'
,password='mypassord'
,authtype='Basic', 
-verb:sync 
-setParamFile:"...\mywebapp.SetParameters.xml" 
-allowUntrusted
```

However, when a package is built a cmd file created. So I called this instead and it worked. Note the cmd expects the setparameter.xml to be in the same directory

```
mywebapp.cmd /t /m:https://MyServer/MSDeploy.axd /u:myusername /p:mypassword /a:basic -AllowUntrusted:True
```

The cmd has a few extra switches that I didn't include so I guess these maybe the issue. I've not tried it, I'm going to stick with the cmd file. The extra switches are

```
-verb:sync -disableLink:AppPoolExtension -disableLink:ContentExtension -disableLink:CertificateExtension
```