# 404 error ASP.NET MVC application hosted on IIS 8.5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I have ASP.NET MVC application hosted on IIS 8.5 on azure vm. I am able to see main page but when I browse for another page I am getting 404 page not found error. All pages are present in application directory. It is working fine on local machine.

Comment: set default page in iis

Comment: @RameshKumar it is showing dashboard not showing another views

Comment: See this answer -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13870561/getting-a-404-from-wmsvc-via-msdeploy-exe

Answer (score 1):

Have you installed WebDeploy on the server? if not then install it and then check. it will work.